# Uploading Ruby on Rails project from github to AWS EC2 instance error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a project my group has created in ruby on rails, I am responsible to uploading it to the AWS EC2 instance from github. I can get this application to work locally but when its on the instance I get an error with sql. We created a new project in the command line and did most work there so we did not personally create a database. I am new to ruby on rails and AWS so I am lost... Thanks in advance! I have attached photos of it working locally and it not working on the instance.[nonworking on ubuntu server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gL29.png) here it is [working locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWnr2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what went wrong, but it looks like you sqlite3 is not connecting to the migration. From your ec2 instance (& in the root directory of your app), you can try to drop the db and migrate =>

```
bundle install
```

And then

```
rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

or

```
rake db:reset
```

You could also look up this tutorial: [DEPLOYING RAILS APP TO EC2 INSTANCE VIA GITHUB](http://www.dsolc.com/blogs/5-deploying-rails-app-to-ec2-instance-via-github)